# how to display the pre value and post value of a column after updating it?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have a jobs database with columns like job_id, title, agency, salary_min, salary_max etc. So i wanna update the salary_max by 2% (i know until this part) and display the old salary and the new salary together to the console. Am I supposed to create another column for it? the thing is I need that old salary just to display at the time of updating. I can discard it after that. I searched online and there are some websites that talk about some trigger functions. but since i'm a beginner, i dont understand those complicated programs. Is there any simple solution to this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: first select old salary and calcualted new salary and show it in the console and then update the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger for that:

```
create or replace trigger display_values
before update on my_table_name
for each row
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Old value: ' || :old.salary);
  dbms_output.put_line('New value: ' || :new.salary);
end;
/
```